# SQL Browser Crashing when running a Nested Query

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, left-join, conditional-aggregation

I have a database with three tables:

1. grocery
2. nutrient
3. grocery_nutrient (for many to many)

Actually, the database is very big and I am facing the problems by running this query, the SQL browser crashes when I run, if I add LIMIT it works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and this is the query I have written for it.

```
SELECT 
  grocery.*, 
  (
    SELECT 
      grocery_nutrient.amount || " " || grocery_nutrient.unit 
    FROM 
      grocery_nutrient 
    WHERE 
      grocery_nutrient.nutrient_id = 2 
      AND grocery.grocery_id = grocery_nutrient.grocery_id
  ) AS calories, 
  (
    SELECT 
      grocery_nutrient.amount || " " || grocery_nutrient.unit 
    FROM 
      grocery_nutrient 
    WHERE 
      grocery_nutrient.nutrient_id = 6 
      AND grocery.grocery_id = grocery_nutrient.grocery_id
  ) AS fats, 
  (
    SELECT 
      grocery_nutrient.amount || " " || grocery_nutrient.unit 
    FROM 
      grocery_nutrient 
    WHERE 
      grocery_nutrient.nutrient_id = 3 
      AND grocery.grocery_id = grocery_nutrient.grocery_id
  ) AS protein, 
  (
    SELECT 
      grocery_nutrient.amount || " " || grocery_nutrient.unit 
    FROM 
      grocery_nutrient 
    WHERE 
      grocery_nutrient.nutrient_id = 4 
      AND grocery.grocery_id = grocery_nutrient.grocery_id
  ) AS carbs 
FROM 
  grocery 
  LEFT JOIN grocery_nutrient ON grocery.grocery_id = grocery_nutrient.grocery_id
GROUP BY 
  grocery.grocery_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query if you use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT g.*, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN n.nutrient_id = 2 THEN n.amount || ' ' || n.unit END) AS calories, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN n.nutrient_id = 6 THEN n.amount || ' ' || n.unit END) AS fats, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN n.nutrient_id = 3 THEN n.amount || ' ' || n.unit END) AS protein, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN n.nutrient_id = 4 THEN n.amount || ' ' || n.unit END) AS carbs
FROM grocery g LEFT JOIN grocery_nutrient n 
ON g.grocery_id = n.grocery_id
GROUP BY g.grocery_id
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, I didn't knew about conditional aggregation